# Does a skewed distribution affect my kruskal wallis ANOVA?

Tags: anova, python, kruskal-wallis-test

I have the following data
[image]

Which is basically, a UserId, the place where he came from, and the Suffix (amount of templates that he saw). The context is that this dataset is from a chatbot sales bot.

When I formulate the population histogram from each origin, I noticed that a lot of users have only one template. Which could be other bots or spawn, but also uninterested users. My question is if there is a good concentration of users in the sample located in the early parts, and all origins may be affected by spawn etc. Would that cause a sort of "bias" into my Kruskal- Wallis ANOVA test? Or since the "bias" is distributed by all groups it may be indifferent?

[image]

Sample squared rooted

[image]

Comment: what happens if you square-root the counts?

Comment: They become even more centralized on the early parts

Comment: Oh but if i dimish bin size in  the graph they start to look like a normal distribution

Comment: pretty zero-inflated! but be careful when you choose the bins. However, I would consider applying a `glm` here, perhaps using a quasipoisson.

Comment: Is not zeros per say they are 1s, the user only has one template displayed

Comment: could you rephrase your problem? I don't get it from your post...